# how to build windows phone 8 offline map load local data on map

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to create a map which shows offline maps from local database like sqlite, also, I need to perform map operation on it, in windows phone 8. I am searching for the same on Google and I got something similar like mapbox sdk https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/ but for android and iOS, not for windows phone 8. Could an body give me an idea about how to go for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use map downloader task for windows phone offline apps..

```
MapDownloaderTask mdt = new MapDownloaderTask();
mdt.Show();
```

For more reference, refer..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206984%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have custom map data which I want show on map not the map which downloaded from default server. I have given reference of mapbox.com which which takes/loads custom custom map data on server and provides API & SDK to receive map data also process map BUT this for Android & iOS not for windows 8 phone and windows 8. So I need help in that.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in [NZ Topo Map](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-nz/store/app/nz-topo-map/b861ab51-a68d-456f-9ae4-cbed66736b36) is spin up a local web service in the app for the map to connect to and request tiles from locally using a [StreamSocketListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener).

In this service, which can be reached via a local url and port number (e.g. http:// 127.0.0.1:[port]/), you would then serve tiles up from within your app however you have them stored.

You need to create your own custom [TileSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.tilesource) to add to the map which would request the map tiles from the local url you have wired up to your [StreamSocketListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener).